# How can I downgrade from ruby 1.9.1 to ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

I just upgraded to rails 3 but was running ruby 1.9.1 prior to the upgrade. Rails 3 doesn't support Ruby 1.9.1. How can I downgrade to ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: What platform are you on? How did you upgrade to 1.9 in the first place (eg: using Macport?, manual download and install?)

Comment: And why not upgrade to 1.9.2 which is in release candidate stage and set to be released in two weeks?

Comment: Like Alkaline says, without knowing how you installed the 1.9.1 release we can't really tell you how to uninstall it.

Comment: I installed it through macports

Comment: upgrade to 1.9.2, since rails 3 supports 1.9.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will downgrade from your current version to 1.8.7:

```
gem update --system 1.8.7
```

Answer (score 9):

install rvm, this will allow you to run multiple versions of ruby and switch between them at will:  [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: I second the suggestion to use rvm when installing multiple versions of Ruby, but rvm doesn't really answer the question the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, its hard to come up with exact solution, in general to downgrade or switch versions for a user:

1. Install Ruby 1.8.7 (or locate it on your system if you have it already)
2. Edit your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file to update your `$PATH` so that the 1.8.7 executable is found first. Something like this:

   ```
   export RUBY_187_HOME='/path/to/1.8.7'
   export PATH=$RUBY_187_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. This is a little similar to what RVM does and it works.
4. To test, try

   ```
   $ which ruby 
   $ /path/to/1.8.7/bin/ruby
   ```