# How to switch rails 4 to rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I have done:

```
gem uninstall rails

gem uninstall railties

gem install rails 3.2
```

And terminal shows this code:

```
Done installing documentation for rails, railties after 1189 seconds
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '3.2' (>= 0) in any repository
2 gems installed
weare138@mycomp:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.5
```

How to fix it?

Comment: After you do `gem uninstall rails`, do `gem list`. What does it show? Please add the result to your question above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I downgrade from ruby 1.9.1 to ruby 1.8.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498681/how-can-i-downgrade-from-ruby-1-9-1-to-ruby-1-8-7)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sjbVc7zr

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the -v flag so rubygems is thinking that 3.2 is the name of a different gem and you are installing the current version (4.1.5). Instead try:

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.19
```

You should not need to remove up-to-date versions as you can specify the older rails version when starting a project with:

```
rails _3.2.19_ new myapp
```

Comment: I need to remove the 4 version?

Comment: As JezC says above, `gem list rails` is useful to see exactly which versions you have installed. Then you can do `gem uninstall rails -v 4.1.5` and any other versions you no longer want followed by `gem cleanup` to remove unneeded dependencies.

Comment: this gem list after command "gem install rails -v 3.2.19" http://pastebin.com/C8yvz8yd  it works?

Comment: You still have some of the dependencies from rails 4.1.5 there. Specifically railties and the top 7 in your list beginning with 'action...' and 'active...'. If you want, you can run `gem uninstall railties -v 4.1.5`, etc. for each of these gems then cleanup again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RVM, create a new gemset

```
rvm gemset create <name>
```

Then you can switch to that gemset using

```
rvm use 1.9.3@<name> #assuming your ruby version is 1.9.3
```

That gives a clean gemset you can install Rails 3.2 to. Maintain multiple gemsets and switch between them